# Running .sh in crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I am running the following script on crontab.

```
@reboot sh  /home/root1/ssh.sh
```

The file `ssh.sh` contains only

```
sudo systemctl start ssh.service
```

But when the device is booted the SSH service is not runnning.

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; vendor preset:>
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
lines 1-5/5 (END)
```

And the output for `cat /var/log/cron.log` as follows.

```
Dec  9 09:40:34 ubuntu cron[843]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Dec  9 09:40:34 ubuntu cron[843]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Dec  9 09:40:34 ubuntu CRON[915]: (root1) CMD (sh  /home/root1/ssh.sh)
Dec  9 09:41:04 ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[709]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Dec  9 09:44:56 ubuntu crontab[3018]: (root1) LIST (root1)
```

Please find the output for `sudo -l` as follows.

```
root1@ubuntu:~$ sudo -l

Matching Defaults entries for root1 on ubuntu: <br/>
    env_reset, mail_badpass,<br/> secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin <br/>

User root1 may run the following commands on ubuntu:<br/>
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/root1/ssh.sh <br/>
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

If I am using "root1        ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD:ALL"  in my sudoers crontab is executing shell script upon reboot.

But however, if I use  "root1 (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/root1/ssh.sh" shell script is not working on reboot even executing it manually prompts for the password.

Comment: Does root1 have sudo access (without a password) to run this command? I'm curious why you don't let systemd start this service instead of using a cron job (`systemctl enable --now ssh`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes, root1 has access.Yep as you mentioned "systemctl enable" is enough to start the service however I am a newbie and trying to learn.

Comment: If you run your script manually, does it prompt for a password?

Comment: Yeah, it is asking for the password :-(
root1@ubuntu:~$ ./ssh.sh 
[sudo] password for root1:

Comment: root1@ubuntu:~$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for root1 on ubuntu:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User root1 may run the following commands on ubuntu:
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/root1/ssh.sh
    (ALL : ALL) ALL

Comment: Add to your question, not as a comment. This is unreadable.

Comment: Since you added the script to `/etc/sudoers`, you need to remove sudo from your script: `systemctl start ssh.service`.

Comment: Unfortunately No luck :-(

Comment: Anything else I would need to try?

Answer (score 0):

Set this up in **root's crontab** instead of a user crontab:

```bsh
$ sudo crontab -e
```

Once your editor is open, then add your `@reboot` command - do not put `sudo` in the `crontab` command.

**NOTE:** *There is no particular security risk to running jobs under root's `crontab`, so long as you use some *common sense*. I feel the most important point here is this: write access to the script you're running should be limited to the root user. This will prevent a "regular" user from making changes to a script that will run with root privileges.*

Comment: This works for me.

But however, if I run it using "crontab -e"(without sudo) it is not working.

What is the issue if is just use "crontab -e"?

Comment: @ArunKumar: Basically the same diff as when you run `sudo` from the command line: `sudo` gives you **privilege elevation**. And so it is w/ the `crontab`. `sudo crontab -e` creates a `crontab` for the root user, and so commands in it execute with root privileges. It generally avoids the messy **authentication** step - messy because it's harder to authenticate a `sudo` command inside a regular user's `crontab` - a cron job can't prompt you for a password like an interactive shell can.

Comment: Well noted @Seamus.

Also, I found another solution  if I add "root1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" in  sudoers then the script is executed upon reboot(with crontab -e)

But  if I add "root1 (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/root1/ssh.sh" in sudoers   neither manually executing shell nor adding  the in crontab works.(Prompts for the password  run it manually),.

Comment: I would not recommend this. You've just given **root1** full access to run any command as root without requiring a password.

Comment: @ajgringo619: Pray tell then... what **would** you recommend for running `cron` jobs with the required privileges?

Comment: In this particular case, as has been mentioned previously, I would enable ssh via systemd; in fact, all systemd services should be started via systemd. If you're just trying to learn about cron, I would try something simple, like a single command that creates a directory or copies a file, just to see if it works.

Comment: @ajgringo619: If that's your opinion, I wonder why you don't write that up as an answer? - just to see if it works. And thank you so much for your helpful suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

In order to run your command from cron, you'll need to add a no-password entry in sudo. Using `sudo visudo`, add this:

```
root1        ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start ssh.service
```

I always use the full path whenever I grant specific sudo command access, so check your system to make sure where `systemctl` lives.

Now, if you decide you want to add to this script later on (although I don't recommend this), you can change the sudo entry to this

```
root1        ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD: /home/root1/ssh.sh
```

then remove sudo from any commands.

Comment: It would be better to simply lot systemd start the service (like any other service), and if they _really_ want to do it from cron, then do it from root's crontab. Fiddling with `sudoers` is needlessly complicated and dangerous (since it allows a non-root user to start a service script that the non-root user has full control over).

Comment: I totally agree; that's why I mentioned that in my first comment. However, if the OP is just trying to learn about cron, then this will get him/her started.

Comment: But your answer isn't mentioning that or even talking about how to use cron.  Consider that you are writing this answer for more people than just the user asking the question. What is the _best_ answer that you can write given an audience of thousands?

Comment: My answer provides a way to run the OP's script from cron; I even mention this in the 1st line of the answer. Btw, my sudoers entry does not allow full access to the ssh service, only to start it.

Comment: Did the same but the issue persist, Am I missing something?



# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

root1   ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD: /home/root1/ssh.sh



Even tried executing the .sh file manually it still prompt for a password.

Comment: Which crontab are you editing, /etc/crontab or via `crontab -e` (for root1)?

Comment: I am using crontab -e

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l` (as root1) to your question.